# Looking for working contour Layer as a WMS or WFS

Tags: wms, wfs, contour

I have had good success in the past with the following Contour layers but as of late neither seem to work:

https://carto.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/contours/MapServer/WMSServer?

https://services.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/WFS/Contours/MapServer/WFSServer?

Where can I find a working layer or how can I make this work?

Here is the error I am getting.
[image]

Comment: can you please be more specific in terms how are you trying to access the services. Are you using the ArcGIS JS API?

Comment: I am adding these as a wms/wfs layer within qgis 3.6.1.  Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: are you able to access the service URL in the web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `https://carto.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/contours/MapServer/WMSServer?` service is working but is scale layered, you'll need to zoom in to see the contours.

[image: Contour service in QGIS]

A working GetMap request for the service (as generated by QGIS) is:

> https://carto.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/contours/MapServer/WmsServer?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=43.62374229720873586,-102.0058404622368329,43.65933876928008317,-101.9465130087845779&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=920&HEIGHT=552&LAYERS=11&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE

The `services.nationalmap.gov` WFS is also working, but if you are zoomed out too far your request will be for a lot of data.  QGIS will give the error, as you report, if the service takes too long to complete the response, but you *MAY* still retrieve all the data requested.

Example WFS GetFeature request as generated by QGIS is:

> https://services.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/WFS/Contours/MapServer/WFSServer?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=WFS_Contours:Contours_Lines_-_Large_Scale&STARTINDEX=0&COUNT=1000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857&BBOX=-11355238.21819610521197319,5401926.45064298808574677,-11348633.91628776118159294,5407398.87103497702628374,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857